# How I can solve this derivative problem?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose $f'(x)$ = 2$x^4$ $f(x^2)$ and $f(1)$ = 2.

Find $f''(x)$ = ${d}/{dx}$ $f'(x)$

I'm having trouble starting this. I was wondering if I work backwards from (1)  = 2 OR use $f(x^2)$ somehow.

How can I solve this?

EDIT: So it looks like my friend miswrote the question, it's now edited. It should be $f'(x)$ = 2$x^4$ $f(x^2)$
NOT
$f(x)$ = 2$x^4$ $f(x^2)$

Comment: It's impossible to have $f(1)=2$ since $f(1) = 2\cdot 1^4 \cdot f(1) \iff f(1) = 0$.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't make sense. Where did you get this question from?

Comment: @Savio How did you get (1) = 0?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose The question was one my friend sent me from a tutorial he was doing. The question is word for word.

Comment: @Broadsword93 Ah I see. Maybe he miscopied down the question or something? Savio is definitely right, in fact in it's current form this is inconsistent. Since it would imply ${f(1)=2=2\times 1\times 2\Leftrightarrow 2=4}$

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Yeah, that's what I was thinking. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Broadsword93, take $x=1$ in functional equation, so $f(1) = 2\cdot 1^4 \cdot f(1^2) = 2 \cdot f(1) \iff f(1) = 2f(1) \iff f(1) = 0$.

Comment: @Savio I understand the substitution, but how does the RHS become 0? I see (1) = 2 (1), but how does 2 (1) = 0 ?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Question now edited. Friend miswrote it.

Comment: @Savio Question now edited. Friend miswrote it.

Comment: Subtracting ${f(1)}$ from both sides gives ${f(1)=0}$, as Savio said. A lot of "paradoxes" rely on the fact that the only solution to this equation is ${0}$ to try and prove ${1=2}$ (notice dividing through by ${f(1)}$ yields ${1=2}$ - but this is not allowed, since we have not checked ${f(1)}$ is $0$, which it is - so maths is not broken)

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Yep, I follow. I just edited the question. There was a mistake writing it out.

Comment: Does it wanted ${f''(x)}$ in terms of ${f(x)}$?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose That's what it looks like. I got the same answer as you.

Comment: Yeah, it's slightly vague. The issue is I'm not quite sure what the ${f(1)=2}$ has to do with it in this case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109454/discussion-between-broadsword93-and-riemannspointynose).

Answer (score 2):

Cool, so as we can see ${f''(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(2x^4f(x^2)\right)=8x^3f(x^2)+4x^5f'(x^2)}$, but ${f'(x)=2x^4f(x^2)}$ and hence ${f'(x^2)=2x^8f(x^4)}$, and so overall

$${f''(x)=8x^3f(x^2)+4x^5\left(2x^8f(x^4)\right)=8x^3f(x^2)+8x^{13}f(x^4)}$$

But yeah, I'm not sure what relevance ${f(1)=2}$ has in this particular case

Comment: It seems to be right, though I wonder what relevance $f(1)$ = 2 had?

Comment: Hmm yeah exactly. It seems redundant if this is the answer it wanted